# What happens to the movie, after it has run out in theaters?

Tags: distribution

After a movie is no longer shown in theaters, what happens to it?

I assume it is kept on a hard drive.
Is the hard drive returned to the publisher or is it kept by the theater?

Is there any way to obtain one of those?

Comment: I mean like the original "huge" Theater file not a downsized copy (for home use).

Comment: I'm not sure about before satellite era. There is a code nowadays using which theater can access the movie and display it. They don't have it after movie had its run.

Comment: Highly related (if not dupe) - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21754/what-format-do-movie-theaters-now-use

Comment: Where do you see an answer to this in that??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With digital distribution, no physical media is shipped. The encrypted film is downloaded into a dedicated secure client,  which receives a decryption key separately.  It is never disclosed. The system then allows only x number of plays within y number of days, before deleting the file. The client hardware is leased and tamper resistant. The server can also require a network connection prior to showing the film, and can deny or delete the film at any given time.